# Django admin filter has_add_permission by test value in model

Tags: django, permissions, django-admin, readonly

I pass my TabularInline in read-only when my user is not super user, and that my status of my model admin table is different from 1, I pass read-only.

But I can't get this same test value applied to has_add_permission.

Admin.py :

```
class ReadOnlyTabularInline(admin.TabularInline):
    """ class Tabular Inline read only """
    extra = 0
    can_delete = False
    editable_fields = []
    readonly_fields = []
    exclude = []


    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        """ status filter readony  """

        if request.user.is_superuser or obj.id_status.id_status == 1:
            return super(ReadOnlyTabularInline, self).get_readonly_fields(request, obj)
        else:
            return list(self.readonly_fields) + \
                   [field.name for field in self.model._meta.fields
                    if field.name not in self.editable_fields and
                       field.name not in self.exclude]
```

I would like use test value

```
if request.user.is_superuser or obj.id_status.id_status == 1:
```

for remove button add

```
def has_add_permissions(self, request):
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dynamic link will not appear if the number of currently displayed forms exceeds max_num .

I'm use max_num = 0 for remove button add

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    """ status filter readony  """

    if request.user.is_superuser or obj.id_status.id_status == 1:
        return super(ReadOnlyTabularInline, self).get_readonly_fields(request, obj)
    else:
        self.can_delete = False
        self.max_num = 0
        return list(self.readonly_fields) + \
               [field.name for field in self.model._meta.fields
                if field.name not in self.editable_fields and
                   field.name not in self.exclude]
```